# how to find occurrences of elements in a list of list in python

Tags: python, list, matrix, count, frequency

I have just started learning python.

I converted an image into a matrix of gray pixels (0=black, 255=white)

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy
import array

im = Image.open("elephant.jpg")                 
grayim = im.convert('L')                        

pixelmatrix = numpy.asarray(grayim)
```

If I

```
print pixelmatrix
```

I get something like:

```
pixelmatrix = [154 154 154 ..., 169 169 169]
              [153 153 153 ..., 166 166 166]
              [153 153 153 ..., 161 161 161]
              ..., 
              [151 130 107 ...,  51  85  75]
              [130 133 111 ...,  86  92  56]
              [ 91 127 119 ..., 102 139  66]]
```

That is what I'm looking for. Ok

What I want to do is evaluate the occurrence of one value, let's say 255.

I tried for cycles and .count method.

```
for x in range(0, lastrow):
    for y in range(0, lastcolumn):
        print sum(pixelmatrix[x,y]
```

They don't work and I cannot understand why. Could you help me?

Thanks a lot
Ciao

Giacomo

Comment: Post the cycles you tried, they were probably almost right.

Comment: show your code to count?

Comment: Define "evaluate" in `evaluate the occurrence of one value, let's say 255`. Are you trying to count how many times `255` occurs in `pixelmatrix`?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget exactly

Comment: @ErikBrodyDreyer  check the post, I updated the for cycle I used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sum`.

```
def pixel_frequency(value, image):
    return (image == value).sum()

pixel_frequency(255, pixelmatrix)
# 137 (or something)
```

Comment: if I print pixel_frequency it says "<function pixel_frequency at 0x10382fc08>"

Comment: `pixel_frequency` is a function that you can use to determine the frequency of any value. Print `pixel_frequency(255, pixelmatrix)` or `pixel_frequency(20, pixelmatrix)` or whatever you want. This code is reusable.

Comment: perfect!! it works!! i tested it with a fully blank image and I got exactly the number of total pixels in there. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy
import array

im = Image.open("elephant.jpg")                 
grayim = im.convert('L')                        

pixelmatrix = numpy.asarray(grayim)

no_occurrences = numpy.sum(pixelmatrix==255)
print(no_occurrences)
```

EDIT: removed redundant step in the code snippet and added print statement.

Comment: Sorry doesn't work...It says "NameError: name 'no_occurences' is not defined
"

Comment: @Giacomo that's impossible, try again.

Comment: the code you suggested is working but If I print no_occurences (as I want to see the occurrence of 255) it says It says "NameError: name 'no_occurences' is not defined "

Comment: @Giacomo I think you merely made a small typo in the variable name. You wrote it with one 'r', I wrote it with two 'r's.

Comment: @Xukrao you are right! it works in this way as well :-) Thanks a lot it was the typo issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about an actual list of lists (there are some commas missing in your post which is why I'm saying this), then try:

```
numOccurrences = sum([row.count(255) for row in pixelmatrix])
```

Comment: Iterating like that requires making a new list, which is inefficient.

Comment: The list only has one `int` per scan line of the image, but yeah it's unnecessary. Lose the square brackets and you're good to go, though.